# Moutain Lion - New line character in notification

Tags: notifications

Do we have any newline character that we can insert in Mountain Lion's Notification Center. I try to append `\n` but it doesn't work.

What I am trying to do here is to write a plugin for alfred. And I use `echo 'test\nnewline'` but it doesn't work. I intend to write this before but it may confuses people with alfred so I didn't write it down :)

Comment: Could you be a little more specific? Development questions are actually off-topic here and are better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: Are you looking to influence the spacing of distinct notifications or embed a character within one notification? A picture of what you want or more detailed use case might help us find you an answer or decide if this is on-topic here. On a user level, notification center isn't something we generally have an API to influence.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you are trying to display the notifications, but this works for me:

```
terminal-notifier -message $'a\nb'
```

`-title $'a\nb'` is not displayed on multiple lines though (even if you replace `\n` with NEXT LINE (NEL)).